# How can a java program decide which command to execute depending of os

Tags: java

I have to make a program which will print the network settings using "ipconfig" for Windows and "ifconfig" for Linux, but I need to do that with a unique implementation for both OS.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the name of the operating system through

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

Have a look at [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/) for some sample code.

---

If it's by any chance the IP of the local host you're interested in, there are ways to get this directly in Java:

- [Getting the IP Address and Hostname of the Local Machine](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Local.html)
- [Get the workstation name/ip](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0390.html)

---

There is no way to determine what the "show ip information"-command is for an arbitrary operating system. You will have to hard-code what the command is (if the is one) for each operating system name manually.

Comment: Thank you. I know that but I need to know how to make the program decide which process to execute at runtime depending of os

Comment: @Tony Ennis: then *"ifconfig"* will work fine... (There's also an ipconfig on OS X, but that one is different).  Besides that, OS X's *ifconfig* is pretty much Linux's *ifconfig*.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the other answers, I'll mention [`SystemUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html) from Commons Lang which exposes various constant such as [`IS_OS_UNIX`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html#IS_OS_UNIX), [`IS_OS_WINDOWS`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html#IS_OS_WINDOWS), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Building on [aioobe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006172/how-can-a-java-program-decide-which-command-to-execute-depending-of-os/4006188#4006188):

```
final String osname = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
String processName;
if(osname.startsWith("win"))
    processName="ipconfig /some /parameter";
else
    processName="ifconfig -some -parameter";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(processName);
```

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here's a concrete [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) that sets a property only for a particular OS:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")) {
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz", "true");
}
```